# How to add lateinit var on extension property

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-extension

What I am trying to do is extend all my actual Fragments by adding another custom class. The problem is that we cannot inherit from 2 different classes, right?

So I am trying to add extension properties by adding:

```
var Fragment.isFocused by Delegates.notNull<Boolean>(false)

fun Fragment.setFocusListenerOn(rootView: View) {
    rootView.onFocusChangeListener = View.OnFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus ->
        this.isFocused = hasFocus
    }
}
```

Why? Because I need to know which Fragment is on top of my BottomNavigation.

Note: each buttomNavFrag is another navigation.

So, I added this function to listen back button:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val callback = requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this) {
        findNavController().navigateUp()
    }
}
```

The problem, that if you are on the second Fragment of all navGraphs, and you click back, all Fragments will listen to the back button. In other words, all navGraphs will return to the first Fragment...

So, before the navigateUp, I would like to add:

```
if (isFocused)
```

But, how to make it work?

**EDIT:**

The thing I want to solve is:
I have multiple web-based Fragments that extends from a class that I added as abstract with code like the following:

```
val callback = requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this) {
    if (webview.canGoBack()) webview.goBack()
    else onBackPressed()
}
```

I only want to navigate back on the webview (if webview can go back) whenever user clicks back button and only if user is on that specific Fragment.
What happens is that only one Fragment (actually the first added) is listening to those changes, instead of all the web-based Fragment.

Answer (score 1):

If you create an extension property that has a backing field or a delegate, as you have, it is a *static* backing field or delegate, meaning it is shared by all instances of the class. This is because it is not possible to add members to a class without subclassing it on the JVM.

You will need to subclass Fragment and use your subclass as the base class for all your Fragments.

That, or some complicated strategy where there is a backing map of Fragments to their states, and you add lifecycle listeners to the Fragments to remove them from the map when they are destroyed.

But for your specific use case, it would probably be easiest to simply check for the current focused view each time you access the property:

```
val Fragment.isFocused: Boolean
    get() = activity?.currentFocus == rootView && rootView != null
```

Though I haven't messed with focus in this way, and I don't know if your fundamental strategy for navigation is flawed. I don't know if checking just the root view will help. And I don't know what you're doing with your callback.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for clarifying. So I edited the question. I am not sure if is because another static field or is because they share the property, so only the first element is listening instead of them all.